# How expand / collapse code regions in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

How to expand / collapse code regions of C# as well as .XAML file in Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 9):

I went into XS' preferences and I see that it's called "code folding" in Text Editor --> General section and I am able to turn that back on.

[image]